# R longitudinal data - Grouping by multiple factors

Tags: r, time-series, tabular

I am still attempting to create a detailed time-series dataframe.  I'm attempting to get monthly data for multiple data points, then group by multiple factors.  I'm not sure this is possible, as I have not seen an example close to this in the documentation, vignettes or on SO.

Here is the sample data I am trying to structure:

```
clients <- 1:100
dates <- seq(as.Date("2012/1/1"), as.Date("2012/9/1"), "days")
categories <- LETTERS[1:5]
products <- data.frame(clientID = sample(clients, 10000, replace = TRUE), 
                       OrderDate = sample(dates, 10000, replace = TRUE), 
                       category = sample(categories, 10000, replace = TRUE),
                       numProducts = sample(1:10, 1000, replace = TRUE), 
                       OrderTotal = sample(1:100, 1000, replace = TRUE))
```

The output looks like this:

```
head(products)
  clientID  OrderDate category numProducts OrderTotal
1       90 2012-03-20        D           9         18
2       66 2012-08-19        A           3         50
3       45 2012-05-25        A          10         75
4       28 2012-01-01        D           4         27
5       71 2012-02-28        A           4         76
6       26 2012-01-28        C           8         89
```

The structure I am trying to get to would look something like this:

```
          Category A                                                                    ...   Category E
ClientID  Jan2012numProducts  Jan2012OrderTotal  Feb2012numProducts  Feb2012OrderTotal  ...  Sep2012numProducts  Sep2012OrderTotal
1         12                  78                 6                   52                      0                   0
2         7                   218                3                   15                      1                   28
...
99999     20                  192                10                  100                     28                  156
```

I realize that the column names will likely get long and would look something like AJan2012numProducts or AJan2012OrderTotal, and that's fine.

Here are the procedures I'm unclear about - Again, I can't find them referenced in the documentation or the vignettes:

1) Can `zoo` aggregate for multiple observation fields?  In this case, I want to get the sum of numProducts and OrderTotal at the same time, for the month. Even if `zoo` can't, I could use the `merge` function and join on clientID and category

2) Can `zoo` group by a factor (or multiple factors) to perform the aggregation?  I want to be able to look at clientID and category by month.

3) Is there an ability to make the dataframe with category and month along the X axis.  If not, if I could get the time-series data to simply group together by clientID and category, I could then use `reshape` to make the time-series wide using `cast`.  I would need to get the dataframe into this structure:

```
head(df)
clientID   Month     category    numProducts  OrderTotal
1        2012-01-31  A           12           78
1        2012-01-31  B           0            0
....
99999    2012-09-30  D           6            71
99999    2012-09-30  E           1            28



cast(df, month~category, sum) (or something close to that)
```

Is any of this possible?  Could you help with some examples?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A combination of using `format.Date`, `xtabs`, and `ftable` gets you pretty much exactly what you ask for. I shortened the example a bit but the principle should be clear. If you wanted the month-field to be shorter you could change the name of the dimension in the table-object or you could make a month-column and redo all the work with that. (I admit I had trouble figuring out how 'zoo' would enter this picture. It looks like a simple tabulation problem at the moment. Although ... I'm sure `aggregate.zoo` is capable of aggregating on multiple criteria and using the sum as the aggregation function.)

First the two commands, then a console session output:

```
prodtble <- xtabs(cbind(numProducts, OrderTotal) ~ clientID + 
                                                  format(OrderDate, "%b%Y") + 
                                                  category, 
                  data=products)
ftable(prodtbl, row.vars=c("category","clientID"))
```

Now the output:

```
> xtabs(cbind(numProducts, OrderTotal) ~ clientID + format(OrderDate, "%b%Y")+category, data=products)
, , category = A,  = numProducts

        format(OrderDate, "%b%Y")
clientID Feb2012 Jan2012 Mar2012
       1      23       0      16
       2       0       6      27
       3      30       0      21
       4      13      33      24
       5       5      20      12

, , category = B,  = numProducts

        format(OrderDate, "%b%Y")
clientID Feb2012 Jan2012 Mar2012
       1       8      27      23
       2       8      14       4
       3       0       5       6
       4       8      13      39
       5       3      23       9

, , category = C,  = numProducts

        format(OrderDate, "%b%Y")
clientID Feb2012 Jan2012 Mar2012
       1       0       6      20
       2      20      20       4
       3       0      17       0
       4      17      11       2
       5       7       3       8

, , category = A,  = OrderTotal

        format(OrderDate, "%b%Y")
clientID Feb2012 Jan2012 Mar2012
       1      40       0      41
       2       0       5      33
       3      48       0      40
       4      16      28      24
       5      23      42      29

, , category = B,  = OrderTotal

        format(OrderDate, "%b%Y")
clientID Feb2012 Jan2012 Mar2012
       1      14      24      19
       2      22      19      19
       3       0       2       4
       4      19      46      62
       5      10      38      10

, , category = C,  = OrderTotal

        format(OrderDate, "%b%Y")
clientID Feb2012 Jan2012 Mar2012
       1       0       2      39
       2      30      33       7
       3       0      44       0
       4      50      21      19
       5      16      14      28
# You could have skipped the printout by assigning to 'prodtable' in the step above.
# I thought is was useful pedagogically.

> prodtbl <- .Last.value

> ftable(prodtbl, row.vars=c("category","clientID"))
                  format(OrderDate, "%b%Y")     Feb2012                Jan2012                Mar2012           
                                            numProducts OrderTotal numProducts OrderTotal numProducts OrderTotal
category clientID                                                                                               
A        1                                           23         40           0          0          16         41
         2                                            0          0           6          5          27         33
         3                                           30         48           0          0          21         40
         4                                           13         16          33         28          24         24
         5                                            5         23          20         42          12         29
B        1                                            8         14          27         24          23         19
         2                                            8         22          14         19           4         19
         3                                            0          0           5          2           6          4
         4                                            8         19          13         46          39         62
         5                                            3         10          23         38           9         10
C        1                                            0          0           6          2          20         39
         2                                           20         30          20         33           4          7
         3                                            0          0          17         44           0          0
         4                                           17         50          11         21           2         19
         5                                            7         16           3         14           8         28
```

This is the shortened example:

```
clients <- 1:5
dates <- seq(as.Date("2012/1/1"), as.Date("2012/3/31"), "days")
categories <- LETTERS[1:3]
products <- data.frame(clientID = sample(clients, 100, replace = TRUE), 
                       OrderDate = sample(dates, 100, replace = TRUE), 
                       category = sample(categories, 100, replace = TRUE),
                       numProducts = sample(1:10, 100, replace = TRUE), 
                       OrderTotal = sample(1:20, 100, replace = TRUE))
```

Comment: Thanks for this.  I'm not sure if the SO formatting is messing me up or not - I can get the `xtabs` line to run, but the `, , category = A,  = numProducts` on part is not working for me.  How should enter that?  After the `xtabs` as subsequent commands?

Comment: Only the lines beginning with ">" are commands;  the other lines are output.